# Android TimerTask

Tags: android

Доброго дня!
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина:

Есть сервис, он запускает задачу по расписанию (5 минут), но задача выполняется совершенно как попало. Может 3 раза без перерыва выполниться, может через три минуты, может через десять.. Как так может быть? Думал может они у меня плодятся, вывел в логи this от задачи - они одинаковые везде, получается что таймер пляшет как хочет? Но разве такое возможно?

Описано так:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    if (!iam_started)
    {
        iam_started = true;

        if (TT==null)
        {
            TT = new myTimerTask();
            T2 = new Timer();
            if (TT != null && T2 != null)
                T2.scheduleAtFixedRate(TT, 1000, 1000*60*5);
        }

        ...

 }
```

Ну и там сам таск:

```
 private class myTimerTask extends TimerTask
 {
     public void run()
     {

     }
  }
```

Вот что я делаю не так?...

Comment: какая версия андроида и выключен ли экран телефона?

Comment: Одно из того что вы делаете не так - так это вообще не придерживаетесь конвенции по именованию классов и переменных в java. И форматирование C++ попахивает.

Comment: @s_klepcha не думаю что это влияет на выполнение кода.

Comment: В андроиде есть службы(а они не мрут, они фоново сидят) а ваше приложение, оно просто приложение которое поработает, закрыли, забыли(или ее выбросили из оперативки). А служба.. (не помню где хорошие коды на этот случай были но дам пример) http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/services-theory.php

Comment: Андроид и 4.4 и 6 - везде одинаково. Самый перл - 20 раз в сек. выполнилась задача...

Comment: Это сервис, он запускается в Foreground. Да, приложение в это время может быть не активным, в том числе и экран может быть выключен. Но сервис то жив. И задачу по таймеру запускает он.

Comment: Стиль кода, ну что же.. кто к чему привык видимо, я на С вырос в свое время. Но, как верно заметили, на выполнение кода это не влияет.